# How to turn simple cycle into a Stream?

Tags: java

How to turn simple cycle into a Stream API?

```
default List<FoodItem> pickMeals(long[] itemsId){
for (int i = 0; i < itemsId.length; i++) {
                pickedMeals.add(getFoodItemById((int) itemsId[i]));
            }
            return pickedMeals;
}
```

UPD Is this correct? I'm not sure if try/catch is added correctly

```
Arrays.stream(itemsId)
                    .mapToObj(itemId -> {
                        try {
                            return getFoodItemById((int) itemId);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return null;
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return pickedMeals;
```

Comment: Why would you need that converted to stream API? just for the learning purpose?

Comment: Yes, we can only use `stream`, no `for`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stream.of` can do that, but it'd be the wrong approach here.

The right question to ask is: How do I turn an array into a stream, and then mutate this stream into looking exactly like I want it to.

```
Arrays.stream(itemsId)
  .mapToObj(itemId -> getFoodItemById((int) itemId))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Lop the collect off if you want to return a `Stream<FoodItem>` instead. You probably shouldn't - list is perfectly fine here.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question. The IDE added try/catch, is this correct? And what should I return from the function instead of pickedMeals?

Comment: You should return that whole expression, which is of type List. That's the one line (well, stick return in front). If these questions are coming up, you need to follow a java 101 course. Your IDE shouldn't be adding try/catch unless getFoodItemById throws a checked exception. If it does throw that, forget about streams, do not use them at all here. Why do you want to? You gain nothing. Make a list, fill it, return it.